# Strange calculations

Tags: mathematics

The question is:

If **7 + 16 = 1000** what is **23 + 42**?

Note, that I currently do not have the solution for this riddle, which is not publicly available.

I have already tried the following:

- Input base 14 and output base 3, which would yield 10022
- Base 987 calculation: 7 + 987*1 + 6 = 1000, 2*987+3+4*987+2 = 5927, which is also wrong.

Any further ideas? I will of course post the solution as soon as it is available!

Comment: I am marking as too broad. Especially since you don't have the answer, what is to say its not just left side + 977 or any other number of basic operations?

Comment: @JesseBarnett Just assume it's not and the solution is more sophisticate, as it always is with good riddles. I presume, that it's good.

Comment: with only one example we cannot establish a pattern, this just encourages people to come up with the most cool-looking solution when there is in fact an *infinite* number of solutions

Comment: @JesseBarnett Maybe you should put some more effort in thinking about this riddle instead of finding excuses why you cannot solve it.

Comment: Is unsolved-mysteries appropriate? Just because you don't have the solution doesn't mean nobody does...

Comment: @thecoder16 The creator of the riddle does, yes. I wasn't sure, if the tag implies that _noone_ has the solution yet. Is there a better tag?

Comment: @Ctx I think it would be best to remove the tag. Unsolved mysteries are problems everyone knows that no one knows the answer to (like the millennium problems in math)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if right answer but if you think in binary you get

> 7 + 16 = 23 => 10111
> Then the inverse = 1000

Do the same for 23 + 42

> You get 23 + 42 = 65 => 1000001

And the Answer

> And the inverse is 101110

Comment: I like this solution, but I fear, it is a bit too far fetched. I'll check if it works out, anyway. (+1 from me)

Comment: Ok, this answer is not accepted for the riddle. I will accept your answer here anyway, since the question is on hold, hence there cannot be more answers, and I appreciate your effort.